# Neither ANDROID_SDK_ROOT in bashrc nor sdk.dir in local.properties is working

Tags: android, linux, react-native, centos

I am trying to run `react-native run-android` inside of a CentOS desktop. I get the following error:

> Could not determine the dependencies of task 'app:installDebug'.
>
> > SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's
> > local properties file at
> > '/home/daniel.cortes/Projects/poc_mobile/android/local.properties'.

So first I go to the root of the react native project and then to the `android/` folder. In there I create a file called `local.properties` and add: `sdk.dir = /home/daniel.cortes/Android/sdk`.

I run `react-native run-android` again and get the same error. So I tried the second option which was to go to `vim ~/.bashrc` and add `export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/daniel.cortes/Android/sdk`, which I did. Then I ran `source ~/.bashrc` and then ran `react-native run-android` and I am still getting the same error. What gives here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try opening the `android/` folder with android studio and let it auto sync. It should generate a `local.properties` file to resolve this issue.